# Как сделать данную svg через border-radius?

Tags: css, svg, изображения

Подскажите как сделать данную svg через фигуру , то есть , при помощи border-radius создать данную фигуру ?

```css
body {
   background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<svg width="168" height="168" viewBox="0 0 240 240" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M35.1472 204.853C18.3649 188.071 6.93599 166.689 2.30577 143.411C-2.32446 120.133 0.0519409 96.0051 9.13446 74.078C18.217 52.1509 33.5977 33.4094 53.3316 20.2236C73.0655 7.03788 96.2662 1.08453e-06 120 0C143.734 -1.08453e-06 166.935 7.03787 186.668 20.2236C206.402 33.4094 221.783 52.1508 230.866 74.078C239.948 96.0051 242.324 120.133 237.694 143.411C233.064 166.689 221.635 188.071 204.853 204.853L187.882 187.882C201.308 174.456 210.451 157.351 214.155 138.729C217.86 120.106 215.958 100.804 208.692 83.2624C201.426 65.7207 189.122 50.7275 173.335 40.1789C157.548 29.6303 138.987 24 120 24C101.013 24 82.4524 29.6303 66.6653 40.1789C50.8781 50.7275 38.5736 65.7207 31.3076 83.2624C24.0415 100.804 22.1404 120.106 25.8446 138.729C29.5488 157.351 38.6919 174.456 52.1178 187.882L35.1472 204.853Z" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.4"/>
        <path d="M204.853 204.853C218.243 191.462 228.275 175.092 234.127 157.082C239.979 139.072 241.485 119.932 238.523 101.228L214.818 104.982C217.188 119.946 215.983 135.257 211.301 149.666C206.62 164.074 198.595 177.17 187.882 187.882L204.853 204.853Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear_615_4113)" fill-opacity="0.75"/>
<defs>
        <linearGradient id="paint0_linear_615_4113" x1="240" y1="99.5349" x2="240" y2="190.233" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop stop-color="#FF0000" stop-opacity="0"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FF0000"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="paint1_linear_615_4113" x1="186.512" y1="32.5581" x2="210.233" y2="56.2791" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0"/>
        </linearGradient>
        </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: А чем svg не угодило?

Comment: Да мне надо заполнить его при помощи джс , а там сложновато как-то оказалось

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 15px solid white;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  opacity: 0.4;
}


body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Такой вопрос , где можно посмотреть данную информацию , как делать svg в фигуры ?

Comment: В целом это обычная вёрстка. Я ничего не переносил, а просто отверстал.

Comment: Не знаю почему не добавилось , как сделать , чтобы в конце этой фигуры было красное ?

Comment: В css нет возможности достаточно просто сделать градиент border'у с border-radius'ом. Придётся делать через наложение двух блоков. Вам точно это нужно? Уверены что тут нет [XY проблемы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/404412)?

Comment: Такая svg, просто тестировал как выглядит без этого , как выглядит без это и в итоге забыл добавить , что я убрал )